# Passage based question to find number of real roots

Tags: calculus

> Consider a thrice differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Graph of a function $y=f(x)$ is symmetrical about line $x=2$ and $f'(1/2)=f'(3)=0$.
>
> $(1)$ Then value of $\displaystyle \int^{\pi+2}_{-\pi+2}f''(x)\ln\bigg[(x-2)+\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}\bigg]dx$
>
> $(a)\; 1\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\; f(2-\pi)\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\; f'(2)\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\; f'(2+\pi)$
>
> $(2)$ Minimum number of roots of $f'(x)f'''(x)+(f''(x))^2=0$ are
>
> $(a)\; 7\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\; 6\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\; 9\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\; 8$
>
> $(3)\;$ if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree with leading coefficients unity and $f(1/2)<0<f(2)$. Then $f(x)=0$ has
>
> $(a)$ No real roots
>
> $(b)$ Exactly two real roots
>
> $(c)$ At least $2$ real roots
>
> $(d)$ Exactly $4$ real roots.

Try: If function is symmetrical about $x=2$ line. Then $f(2+x)=f(2-x)$

So $(1)\displaystyle \int^{\pi+2}_{-\pi+2}f''(x)\ln\bigg[(x-2)+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}\bigg]dx$

Put $(x-2)=t$. Then $dx=dt$ and changing limits

$$=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f''(t+2)\ln\bigg[t+\sqrt{t^2+1}\bigg]dt$$

$$=-\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f''(2-t)\ln\bigg[t+\sqrt{t^2+1}\bigg]dt$$

Could some help me to solve it and also for other parts. Thanks

Comment: For part (1), at least, integrate by parts and use the fact that $f'(2 - t)$ and $\log(t + \sqrt{t^2+1})$ are both odd.

Comment: I think you would get less downvotes if you restricted your question to part 1 and tried using the method proposed by @anomaly. If you still have trouble, I'm pretty sure someone will be willing to help.

Comment: Updated, fixed the bug in the part 2.

Comment: One easy way to improve your Question would be giving a better title.  The various parts of your Question are related by the setup of function $f$, but there's not much evidence of your having thought about the last two parts before posting. You've been around awhile, so I'm concerned that you may need to review [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

$$\mathbf{(1)}$$
$$I=\int_{2-\pi}^{2+\pi}f''(x)\ln(x-2+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1})\,dx = {\int_{2-\pi}^{2+\pi}\ln(x-2+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1})\,df'(x)},$$
wherein
$$(\ln(x-2+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}))' = (x-2+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1})^{-1}(1+\dfrac{x-2}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}}) = \dfrac1{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}}$$
and
$$f(2-x) = f (2+x)\rightarrow f'(2-x) = -f'(2+x),\tag1$$
i.e. $f'(2+x)$ is odd function.

So by parts
$$I = f'(x)\ln(x-2+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1})\bigg|_{2-\pi}^{2+\pi} - \int_{2-\pi}^{2+\pi}\dfrac {f'(x)dx}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}}$$
$$ = {f'(2+\pi)\ln((\pi+\sqrt{\pi^2+1})(-\pi+\sqrt{\pi^2+1}))} - 
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac {f'(2+y)dy}{\sqrt{y^2+1}} = \boxed{f'(2+\pi)}.$$
Answer: $\mathbf{(d)}.$

---

$$\mathbf{(2)}$$
Let $g(x)= f'(x-2).$ Then, using $(1),$
$$g(-x) = -g (x)\rightarrow g(0) = 0.\tag{2a}$$
Besides,
$$\quad g\left(-\dfrac32\right) = g(-1) = g(1) = g\left(\dfrac32\right)=0,\tag{2b},$$
$$f'(x)f'''(x) + \left(f''(x)\right)^2 = \left(f'f''(x)\right)' = (g(x+2)g'(x+2))' = 0.$$
Equations $(2)$ gives the roots of $g(x),$ wherein these roots divide the intervals with the roots of $g'(x).$

At least, there are 5 roots of $g(x)$ and four roots of $g'(x).$

Answer: $\mathbf{(c)}$

---

$$\mathbf{(3)}$$

The polynomial degree is not specified in the conditions. Taking in account the contest, let us consider
$$n = 4,6.$$
The polynomials $f(x)$ and
$$P_n(x) = f(x-2)$$
have the same quantity of roots.
Then 
$$P_n(-x) = P_n(x),\quad P'_n\left(-\dfrac32\right) = P'_n(-1) = P'_n(1) = P'_n\left(\dfrac32\right)=0,\tag3$$
$$P_n\left(-\dfrac32\right) < 0 < f(0).$$

**Case** $\mathbf{n=4}.$

The polynomial of the $4$th order with 4 derivative zeros is constant.

Required polynomial doesn't exist.

**Case** $\mathbf{n=6}.$

Polynomial $P_6$ is even, so
$$P_6(x) = P_3(x^2).$$
Taking in account $(3),$ the derivative is odd and can be written in the form of 
$$P'_6(x) = Ax(x^2-1)(4x^2 - 9) = A(4x^5 - 13x^3 + 9x)\tag4$$
([see also graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x(x%5E2-1)(4x%5E2-9))), then
$$P_6(x) = \dfrac1{12}A(8x^6 - 39x^4 + 54x^2 + z),$$
where 
$$Az= 12P_6(0) > 0,\tag5$$
$$12P_6(-3/2) = \dfrac{243}{16}A+Az < 0,\tag6$$
$$12P_6(-1) = A(23+z).$$ 
From $(5),(6)\rightarrow A<0,\quad z<0,$ and then 
$$
\begin{cases}
P_6(x)>0\text{ if } z<-23 \\
P_6(x)= 0\text{ if } z = 23 \\
P_6(x)<0\text{ if } z > -23
\end{cases}
$$
([see also graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20-1(8x%5E6-39x%5E4%2B54x%5E2%20-%2025))).

If $n=6$, then

Answer: $\mathbf{(c)}.$